# Changing target compiler in VS 2013 to VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a VS 2012 project that worked fine till the template issues in c++ started causing problems in VS 2013.

Some one mentioned changing the compiler to VS 2012 in the settings will fix the issue by using the same compiler the VS 2012.

Steps to do this i was told was to first install VS 2012 then change the setting in the project properties.

How there does not seem to be a setting to change the compiler.

How do I change the compiler in VS 2013 to VS 2012?

=============== EDIT ===============

herohuyongtao below explained the compiler change Thx

However despite installing VS2012. VS2013 properties does not see VS2012 when i hard code the value 110 it says "Visual Studio 2012 (v110) (Not Installed)"
any thoughts on how to resolve that?

=============== EDIT ===============

The version of VS 2012 is express which is registered now. Will this work with VS 2013 pro?

=============== EDIT ===============

Also just installed Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=38807

as recommend by the compiler error when tried to compile with v110 even though it was not there

Comment: Project + Properties, General, Toolset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the project in `Solution Explorer` and select `Properties`, and then:

```
Configuration Properties > General > Platform Toolset > v110.
```

Comment: @abe Try to restart and see how it goes.

Comment: already restarted, how ever i am using express does that make a difference further more i have not registered it yet with the free serial do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: @abe It could be, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: registered it created a project in 2012 compiled it then rest machine still no joy any thoughts?

Comment: @abe Still cannot find `v110` toolset in VS13?

Comment: ya its still not there and i just installed the visual studio tools for applications 2012 as well but not v110 in the menu (Restarted machine too)

Comment: well this it he correct way of changing compilers if you can install the 2012 compiler